# Spring - JPA - Transactions

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactional

I have a method annotated with `@Transaction` in my business layer . It inserts into two different entities.

```
@Transaction
void method (){
try{
  service1.insertOne();
  service2.insertTwo();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
// log exception
}
}
```

Both methods throw a custom exception when the validation fails.

The problem I am facing is if insertOne is successful and insertTwo throws a validation exception, the transaction is not being rolled back. i.e data in insertOne is being inserted.

Comment: Have you got XA data sources configured? Have you got an actual transaction manager implementation such as bitronix on the classpath? A transaction won't work unless you have datasource or message bus configured...

Comment: I use the default spring boot jpa configuration with hibernate.

Comment: It will treat the two writes as separate transactions, unless you configure for global XA transaction, which means using Bitronix or similar. The default JPA TM only supports single not global transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Such case appears just because you catch generic exception in your method,
so that "transaction aspect" doesn't know anything about your validation error.
In this case, if exception isn't thrown, transaction commits as successfull